# Play Framework "eclipsify" command throws error, cannot find sbt_2.9.1;0.13.5

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, playframework, sbt

I've never used scala before, this is a requirement for an interview test. When I try run the `play eclipsify` command I get the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
Getting org.scala-tools.sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.13.5 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.13.5

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Programming\play-2.0\framework\..\repository/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.13.5/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== Maven2 Local: tried

          file://C:\Users\Paul/.m2/repository/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.9.1-0.13.5.pom

        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

          http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.13.5/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== Maven Central: tried

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.9.1-0.13.5.pom

        ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried

          http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.9.1-0.13.5.pom

        ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository: tried

          http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.9.1-0.13.5.pom

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.13.5: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.13.5: not found
```

I've spent a lot of time looking online for a solution, but nothing has worked so far, and to be honest I'm not even sure what I'm looking for.
Is it possible to point play at the correct repository? if so where is that?
Can I tell play to use an older version? How can I do that?

I've spent practically the whole day yesterday trying to set up the environment properly, with very little success. 
In the end, I managed to get a project template running by installing Intellij and importing through that, but using Intellij to do this project is not good, I've no experience with that either, and it's slowing me down significantly.
If I could get this project up and running in eclipse I think I could get through this coding challenge no problem, quickly. Can anyone help me resolve these issues?

Comment: Which Play version are you using? If that Play project is public add a link to it.

Comment: I'm using the latest one, 2.3.6. The project is the default java project template built using 'activator new' as done in the getting started tutorial with java. That's as far as I've managed to get with eclipse. When I run 'play eclipsify' I get the error. the version of sbt installed was 0.13.6, I've uninstalled it and manually installed 0.13.5, but still 'play eclipsify' gives the same error above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably mixing two different versions. You should not use `play` but `activator` only. In fact `play` command is not available anymore (so unless you added an alias named play to execute activator you are using a different version). Also `eclipsify` only works on older versions (now is called `eclipse`).

So try again following those steps:

```
$ activator new
(Choose Java or Scala Play template)
Enter a name for your application (just press enter for 'play-java')
> sometest

$ cd sometest
$ ./activator eclipse
```

Comment: Thank you! so, so much!! That information isn't in the tutorial, and I didn't see it on the page about setting up your IDE, which still refers to 'eclipsify' and using play.

Comment: @bot_bot ... you checked wrong version apparently https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE - uses `eclipse` and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23 talks about `activator` on the beginning, if you found any references to `play eclipsify` command in docs for 2.3.x commit it to the authors

Comment: Yeah I realise that now, I'm not sure how I got there, I'll go through the steps again once I've completed the test and report any errors, but I think you're right.